# Python django_static

Tags: python, django, django-static

I'm having trouble to render a python app that someone sent me.

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
DJANGO_STATIC = True
DJANGO_STATIC_NAME_PREFIX = '/static'
DJANGO_STATIC_SAVE_PREFIX = '/tmp/cache-archinot


INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_static',
)
```

When I run the server I get:

```
ImportError: No module named django_static
```

I downloaded the zip from

```
https://github.com/peterbe/django-static
```

But I don't know where to put what I downloaded. Please help I'm new to python django etc..
Ohh lastly if I comment the line

```
#'django_static',
```

Then the server runs but I can't render any page since they are using django_static as a template...

Thank you

Comment: Extract `django-static` somewhere, cd to the directory, and install it by running `python setup.py install`.

Answer (score 0):

Install `django-static` using `pip` or `easy_install`.

`pip install django-static`

OR

`easy_install django-static`.

Here you can see configuration instructions if you face any problem.

https://github.com/peterbe/django-static